# Specifying a select clause in Laravel's eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tables

```
category                 category_path
---------------          ----------------
id                       category_id
title                    path_id
                         level
```

Queries

```
    CategoryPath::with('Category')
        ->select('*', DB::Raw('group_concat(title ORDER BY level SEPARATOR " &gt; ") as name'))
        ->groupBy('category_path.category_id')->paginate(10);
```

I get an error `Unknown column 'title'` in `group_concat`.

How can I make selections from the related table?

**Simple Solution:**

Use model class instead of DB class then query will maintain eloquent relationships:

```
$categories = CategoryPath::select('*', DB::Raw('group_concat(title ORDER BY level SEPARATOR " &gt; ") as name'))
    ->leftJoin('category', 'category_path.path_id', '=', 'category.id')
    ->groupBy('category_path.category_id')
    ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Why do you only want to access certain attributes?

Comment: I need to group_concat category title so it prints out as full path like `Computers > Parts > CPU`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `lists()` method.

```
$categoryPath = CategoryPath::with('category')->paginate(10);

foreach($categoryPath as $path) {
    echo implode(' > ', $path->category->lists('title'));
}
```

That should have the desired affect, although I am making some assumptions.

Comment: This would work but I'd rather write full query using the query builder. I wonder if i can make this using eloquent relationships.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `title` part of `group_concat()` to `category.title`?

Comment: Yes i tried. Had same error `Unknown column 'category.title`.

Comment: I think your best bet is the method I suggested above, or switching to `DB` for this.